How to make RSIS to move on vumanchu like crypto faces does on his market cipher b which smoothing and inputs do i have to use?
enter image description here
here i got example of someones else indicator the guy who made this copied two rsis i dont know how as you can see in photo purple > blue and white(RSI) i would like to make that also on vumanchu but idk how cause this indicator is free trial and there is no source code , so if someone knows who could help me with this i would really appreaciate it please answer if you know !! thanks
i tried to change inputs but i cannot figure out which ones should i use to make it behave like market cipher b

Stackoverflow is not a coding service. To get an answer, you must share your code. What you tried, or reproduce the unexpected behavior.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I've been working on this for a long time, I think that together we can do more, write me an e-mail and we'll talk - pawelknot0@gmail.com
